# WCF Service with multiple threads Issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, wcf

I have a wcf service hosted under IIS 6.0/win 2003 machine. Service has a method  like this.

```
    List<CustomObject> ProcessImageData(List<CustomObject> lstData)
    {
          lstSharedProcessedImages = lstData;

         for (int idx = 0; idx < lstData.Count; )
         {
            CurrentThreadRoom = MAX_THREAD_COUNT - ThreadRunningCount;
            for (int ctr = 0; ctr < CurrentThreadRoom; ctr++)
            {
                runBrowserThread(lstData[idx].Url, lstData[idx].Path);
                idx++;
                if (lstData.Count == idx)
                    break;
            }
            while (ThreadRunningCount >= MAX_THREAD_COUNT)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(SleepTimeMiliseconds);
            }
        }
        while (ThreadRunningCount > 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(SleepTimeMiliseconds);
        }
        return lstSharedProcessedImages; 
    }
```

### web.Config (service) file

```
    <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfServices.Service1Behavior" name="WcfServices.HtmlToImageService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="LargeSizeMessages" contract="WcfServices.IHtmlToPngService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
   </service>

    <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WcfServices.Service1Behavior">
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1000" maxConcurrentSessions="1000" maxConcurrentInstances="1000"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553500"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
   </behaviors>
```

### Client's app.config file

```
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IHtmlToImageService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
      allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
          algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
```

only one client calls the wcf service's method in a loop and wait one minute for each iteration to receive the results. The wcf service spawns 10 threads (all independent and NOT relying on each other) to fulfill each request. Each one of these threads creates a WebBrowser instance to do its job. It usually takes 6-7 seconds to process the request and send a response back to client. Around 80% of the calls are successful.

Now the problem is,

1. On the web server we see a huge spike in the number of threads (from 13k total to around 18k) when client calls the service method. The service is supposed to create 10 threads/request and there is no specific code which'd terminate the thread when it is done. Assumption is that thread dies its own death (also release memory etc.) as soon as the job given is complete.
2. For some reason, A lots of threads remains in the memory which makes server non-responsive. Also not sure why such a huge spike in the #of threads.
3. Then all subsequent calls to server fails. Client keeps calling with new requests and continues to have the following exceptions.

"This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down).", "The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9749975." etc etc...

when the memory is recollected and thread count is again down to 13k or something, service becomes functional again, process request, # of thread spikes up, new exceptions and the vicious circle continues.

What is going wrong here ?? Assuming the #of threads in memory is the culprit, how can I force the clean up on the server ? thread clean up appears to be happening anyway but too late cuz too many exceptions by then.

what you guys suggest ? Highly appreciate any input !!!

Comment: You've shown us a pseudo-code signature, not even a real one, but actual code would be what we need.

Comment: Sorry. Code is there now for review.

Comment: Thanks, but where is the code for `ProcessImageData`?

Comment: Done. pls see above.

Comment: Is that your actual code? Or is it "like" your actual code?

Comment: In any case there are so many issues with the code you've posted I can imagine you're having problems. Please make sure you post the **full** actual code - that includes all of the fields, properties, and supporting methods.

Comment: It is the actual code. Although there is a lot more. I am not sure if I can post everything over here. Let me try.

Comment: You said "Service has a method like this" in your question which makes it sound like it isn't actual code. Now, the code you've posted doesn't have enough info to show why your code is failing. You need to show the rest. You could start with the fields/properties used and the `runBrowserThread` method, but I expect I'll be asking for more later.

Comment: sorry "like this" was a typo from my original post. anyway, unfortunately I don't know how (if at all) I could post the entire project.

Comment: You understand that what you've given us is not enough to explain what's going on? You need to a [mcve] (or at least something much closer than what you've given us so far).

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell, given that you have not shared any code or configuration. One could suspect that all the treads don't finish so that the number of threads increases by e.g. 10 for each call, if none of them finish.

You could use a profiler or PerfMon to monitor the number of threads or add trace-calls and a trace listener to your service to find out more.

Comment: Sorry. Code is there for review.